# Changing the default formating view for Type system.io.directoryinfo.format.ps1xml

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction or share with me  a working example of this `system.io.directoryinfo.format.ps1xml` being configured correctly.

Reading the documentation articles of [about Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3) and [Out-Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default?view=powershell-7.3) I was able to figure out how to export default "Type" view formatters modify them and then reimport them.

But I am stuck on manually and correctly modifying this file

The expected result I am looking for is to remove the table header, and the directory name that is printed above the table header

[image]

As for the properties, it should be:

- `Basename`
- `Extension`
- `LastAccessTime`
- `Directory` or Parent folder

So that the end result I am aiming for looks like this:
[image]

In once instance, I attempted to remove the entire node `TableHeaders`:

```
        <TableHeaders>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Label>Mode</Label>
            <Width>7</Width>
            <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Label>LastWriteTime</Label>
            <Width>26</Width>
            <Alignment>Right</Alignment>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Label>Length</Label>
            <Width>14</Width>
            <Alignment>Right</Alignment>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Label>Name</Label>
            <Alignment>Left</Alignment>
          </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
```

Which gives me view like this:

```
ModeWithoutHardLink LastWriteTimeString LengthString NameString
------------------- ------------------- ------------ ----------
d----               07/02/2023    19:18              Some folder
```

Further edits and then attempting to reimport the editing `xml` file just gives me error:

```
Update-FormatData: Errors occurred while loading the format data file:
```

I spent all day attempting to understand this and I am at my witts end now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**CustomControl `ExpressionBinding` Tag**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.3#customcontrol-tag) to get that output you're looking thru a format `ps1xml` file however you should note, since you're interested in displaying objects as if they were strings, there is no way to handle dynamic padding with this method.

Your format file should look like this:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>CustomIODisplay</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</TypeName>
        <TypeName>System.IO.FileInfo</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <CustomControl>
        <CustomEntries>
          <CustomEntry>
            <CustomItem>
              <ExpressionBinding>
                <ScriptBlock>
                  '{0,-25}{1,-10}{2,-20:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}{3}' -f @(
                      $_.Basename
                      $_.Extension
                      $_.LastAccessTime
                      $_.DirectoryName
                  )
                </ScriptBlock>
              </ExpressionBinding>
            </CustomItem>
          </CustomEntry>
        </CustomEntries>
      </CustomControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Then you can `Update-FormatData`:

```
Update-FormatData -PrependPath path\to\my\test.format.ps1xml
```

Then `Get-ChildItem` update would look more or less like you wanted:

```
PS ..\pwsh> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\ -File | Select-Object -First 10 

bfsvc                    .exe      15/01/2023 19:21:46 C:\Windows
bootstat                 .dat      07/02/2023 15:00:22 C:\Windows
comsetup                 .log      15/08/2021 02:44:15 C:\Windows
Core                     .xml      07/02/2023 10:24:46 C:\Windows
CoreSingleLanguage       .xml      05/02/2023 17:12:19 C:\Windows
diagerr                  .xml      05/02/2023 17:12:19 C:\Windows
diagwrn                  .xml      05/02/2023 17:12:19 C:\Windows
DirectX                  .log      15/08/2021 02:44:15 C:\Windows
DPINST                   .LOG      15/03/2022 13:17:14 C:\Windows
DtcInstall               .log      15/08/2021 02:44:15 C:\Windows
```

A much simpler solution to the problem would be to use [`Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.3#-hidetableheaders), then the cmdlet can handle dynamic padding for you:

```bash
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\ -File |
    Format-Table Basename, Extension, LastAccessTime, DirectoryName -HideTableHeaders
```

Comment: Hey hanks allot for this. Your XML solution gets me there but sadly you are right about this "dynamic padding" feature. it renders lines unreadable, espacially when you have long and short paths.

Since I need this dynamic padding, it is not possible to just take the default view `system.io.directoryinfo.format.ps1xml` and hide\remove table headers? I feel I can figure out the rest if I can just achieve this.

Comment: I have been using a custom function, that internally does something simmilar to `Format-Table Basename, Extension, LastAccessTime, DirectoryName -HideTableHeaders`  but specifying `Get-ChildItem | FormatFunc` is not ideal, further more I am really looking for a universal function that is always applied to every `system.io.directoryinfo` output view such as `New-Item`, `Copy-Item`, `Get-Item` etc

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer by [santiago-squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) gives a good base, but I think you can get better.
You've mentioned you appreciate dynamic padding feature, which is part of table-view. So maybe you should use tableControl instead of customControl.

`Directory: C:\blabla` part of output is shown when grouping of entries is applied, it wouldn't be there if there is no grouping. And also there is a `<HideTableHeaders>` tag which can be used in `<TableControl>`. So your desired format.ps1xml file can look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>CustomIODisplay</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>System.IO.DirectoryInfo</TypeName>
        <TypeName>System.IO.FileInfo</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <!-- <Wrap /> -->
            <TableColumnItems>
                <TableColumnItem>
                    <PropertyName>Basename</PropertyName>
                </TableColumnItem>
                <TableColumnItem>
                    <PropertyName>Extension</PropertyName>
                </TableColumnItem>
                <TableColumnItem>
                    <PropertyName>LastAccessTime</PropertyName>
                </TableColumnItem>
                <TableColumnItem>
                    <PropertyName>DirectoryName</PropertyName>
                </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
        <HideTableHeaders>true</HideTableHeaders>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Import it: `Update-FormatData -PrependPath .\format.ps1xml`

About this `<Wrap>` element - not sure what it's about, also there is a `<WrapTables>`, maybe you will figure it out how to use them from [xml schema](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Schemas/Format.xsd).
Also there are those `<Width>` and `<Alignment>` elements with which you can play around. And if you want to colorize some columns, probably you will have to use `<ScriptBlock>` as it was used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081733/20340543).